# Issue with a piece of code regarding the calculation of a determinant

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, matrix

I've written a piece of code that's supposed to calculate the determinant and I've spent the last 2 hours looking at the code unsure of where exactly the error is. I am open for any criticism and tips. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int deter(vector < vector<float> >& mm, int vm);

int main () {
    vector< vector<float> > m; //Declaration of the 2D vector
    int vel; //Size of the matrix
    cout << "Unesite velicinu matrice: ";
    cin >> vel;
    m.resize(vel, vector<float> (vel)); //Resizing to the actual size
    for (int i = 0; i < vel; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vel; ++j) {
            cout << "m[" << i << "][" << j << "]: "; //Input
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Pregledno ispisana matrica:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < vel; ++i) {
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < vel; ++j) {
            cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << "Determinanta vase matrice je: " << deter(m, vel); //Calling the function.
    return 0;
}

int deter(vector < vector <float> >& mm, int vm) { //Passing by reference
    int pr;
    float d = 0;
    vector <float> racun; //Used to recursively call the deter function and save the result
    vector < vector <float> > matri;  //2D Vector
    matri.resize(vm, vector<float> (vm)); //Resizing
    racun.resize(vm);
    if (vm == 2)
        return (mm[0][0] * mm[1][1]) - (mm[0][1] * mm [1][0]); //Case of a 2x2 matrix
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < vm; ++i) { //Main loop
            int br1 = 0, br2 = 0; //counters
            for (int j = 0; j < vm; ++j) {
                for (int k = 0; k < vm; ++k) {
                    if (j != 0 && k != i) { //Doing the Laplace's expansion, first row.
                        matri[br1][br2] = mm[j][k];
                        ++br2;
                        if (br2 == vm-1){
                            ++br1;
                            br2 = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            pr = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                pr = -1 * pr; //Plus or minus.
            }
            racun[i] = pr * deter(matri, vm-1); //Saving the calculation of each matrix with the ignored row and column
            }
        for (int j = 0; j < vm; ++j) {
            d += mm[0][j] * racun[j]; /*Actual determinant calculation, the mm[0][j] signifies
                                           that it is Laplace's expansion using the first row*/
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

For the sake of testing, the determinant of a 3x3 matrix:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
should print out 0.
The issue is that it dumps the core at the last row.

Comment: What are you seeing going wrong?

Comment: It terminates the program on the last row. I'm not exactly sure where the error is

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: If your program ends on the last row that may mean you have exceeded the length of your Vector or Array. Most likely array since Vectors have a dynamic size.

Comment: No crash reported using GCC 4.7.2 on compileonline.com - output was "Unesite velicinu matrice: Pregledno ispisana matrica:
Determinanta vase matrice je: 0" - this is expected?

Comment: The debugger doesn't give me much, everything seems fine there, and the output depends on the matrix you've entered, however I have found a calculation error, where it says if (br2 > vm) it should instead say if (br2 == vm-1). Also Andrew, the code seems to work fine when I replace vectors with a statically allocated 2D array. Anyone knows how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue may be that you never assign a size to the `racun` vector which means that the line:

```
 racun[i] = pr * deter(matri, vm-1);
```

is undefined behavior (see [Setting std::vector contents directly using operator []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525351/setting-stdvector-contents-directly-using-operator) for more details). Resize it like you do `matri` before using it.

Another things I noticed which could be an issue with your algorithm is the loop summing `d` at the end should be outside of the main `for (i...` loop (not too sure about this so double-check).